# When do different cyclic subgroups of same order share the neutral element only?

Tags: group-theory, prime-numbers, cyclic-groups

When do different cyclic subgroups of same order share the neutral element only?

They do if their order is prime as each element of each group (but the neutral one) generates the hole group; therefore, if distinct elements exist the groups must be different.

Is there a more general criterion?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Different cyclic groups of the same order?  Cyclic groups of a fixed order are unique.

Comment: Sorry, I am speaking of cyclic subgroups of a group.

Comment: Same thing applies.  A cyclic subgroup is still a group itself.  Any two cyclic (sub)groups of order $n$ are unique.  Technically I should say unique up to isomorphism.  So if you have two cyclic (sub)groups that don't look identical, they are still isomorphic.

Comment: I am not concerned with isomorphism. I want to count elements.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.  Your title is "When do different cyclic subgroups of same order share the neutral element only?" and the answer is "Never, because there aren't *different* cyclic subgroups of the same order."  What do you mean by count elements?  Count elements in what?

Comment: @tilper Different doesn't mean non-isomorphic, e.g. if $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ then $G$ has 3 different cyclic subgroups of order $2$, namely $\mathbb{Z}_2\oplus 0$, $0\oplus\mathbb{Z}_2$ and the diagonal $\{(0,0), (1,1)\}$. He's talking about counting elements of two subgroup of some group obviously.

Comment: Ah.  "Different doesn't mean non-isomorphic."  News to me, thanks.  This makes sense now.  And obviously that wasn't obvious to me.  :)  $\qquad$

Comment: Exactly. For example, you can exclude some possibilities for the number of p-sylowgroups if other q-sylowgroups occupy a certain number of elements.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a "more general criterion", but if you're looking at cyclic subgroups of order $n = pm$ with $p$ a prime and $m \neq 1$, i.e., any nonprime order, then $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ has cyclic subgroups of order $n$ which intersect nontrivially, namely those generated by $(1, 0)$ and $(1, 1)$, both of which contain $(p, 0) \neq (0, 0)$.